# Use a variable as part of name of an array name?

Tags: bash, variable, array

I essentially have a for loop where the variable `i` that I am iterating with will take on each letter of the alphabet, for example. I want to use each value of `i` to create an array called `"$i"array` (for instance `aarray`, `barray`, `carray`, `darray`, etc) or even just called `"$i"` (so the arrays could be called `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc.).

What kind of syntax could I use to make this happen?

I have tried:

```
for i in ${alphabet[@]}; do
    "$i"array[0]=0
done
```

and once I have my group of arrays, could I iterate through them by doing

```
for i in ${alphabet[@]}; do
    "$i"array[0]=1
done
```

Comment: Ouch, please don't. Use an associative array

Answer (score 2):

Can I offer other way (via associative array) to do your task? It seems more clever and acceptable:

```
declare -A array
for i in ${alphabet[@]}; do
  array[$i]=0
  # or array[${i}0]=0 if you need 
done
```

So you can iterate through it by `for i in ${!array[@]}` or same way`for i in ${alphabet[@]}`

Comment: Or use a pseudo 2-dimensional array: `array[$i,0]=1`

Comment: @glennjackman By the way is there some advantage to use "pseudo 2-dimensional" array instead of ordinary associative one?

Comment: From the question, sounds like he wants an array-of-arrays. This can be implemented with my suggestion

Comment: @glennjackman Sure. But is there difference between `${i},0` and `${i}0` or `$i 0`? How I understand any of variants just treated as `string` no matter with or without separator(s) inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` builtin to evaluate the variable name. An example that illustrates the point:

```
i="a"
eval ${i}lphabet="abcde"
echo $alphabet
```

However, retrieving the value from `${i}lphabet` requires another trick. You have to use the *value* of a variable as a variable name (essentially a pointer). The syntax would be:

```
#declare a variable that names the other variable:
pointer=${i}lphabet
#dereference the name with the ! syntax:
echo ${!pointer}
```

Applied to your case:

```
for i in ${alphabet[@]}; do
    pointer="$i"array
    eval ${pointer}[0]=0
done
```

However, this is a bad design... you should find a more conventional way of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `eval` to use the contents of variables as variable names:

```
for i in ${alphabet[@]}; do
    eval "$i[0]=1"
done
```

`eval` takes its arguments and evaluates it in the context of the shell, i.e. not as a separate shell, attempts to do this without `eval` will result in separate shells being started and hence the variables set will not be available in the first shell.